# How to get all relationships between a set of nodes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

In general, the problem is: there is a query with (variable length) matches of node:

```
MATCH (a:`SOME.LABEL.1` {...})
MATCH (b:`SOME.LABEL.2` {...})
MATCH (c:`SOME.LABEL.3` {...})
...
MATCH (z:`SOME.LABEL.n` {...})
```

I need to get all relationships between this set of nodes. I started thinking about searching of distinct combinations of (a, b, c, ..., z):

```
WITH a,b,c, ..., z

MATCH (a) -[ab]-> (b)
MATCH (a) -[ac]-> (c)
...
MATCH (z) -[za]-> (a)

RETURN ab, ac, ..., za;
```

But I think its too complex.

There is an `apoc` function. `apoc.algo.cover` does what I need, but, unfortunately, I need to do it with pure cypher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
WITH ['LAB1', 'LAB2', 'LAB3', 'LAB4'] AS labs
MATCH (n)-[r]->(m)
WHERE
  ANY(l1 IN labs WHERE l1 IN LABELS(n)) AND
  ANY(l2 IN labs WHERE l2 IN LABELS(m))
RETURN r
```

But if you are using neo4j 5, the [newer label expression syntax](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/expressions/#label-expressions) will likely be more performant:

```
MATCH (:LAB1|LAB2|LAB3|LAB4)-[r]->(:LAB1|LAB2|LAB3|LAB4)
RETURN r
```

Comment: This feels very repetitive. Is there a way to write `:LAB1|LAB2|LAB3|LAB4` only once with the new syntax?

Comment: It only repeats the list once, so I wouldn't say its "very" repetitive :-). But if you wanted to, you could just give all the `LABn` nodes an additional label, say `LABX`, and then just do `MATCH (:LABX)-[r]->(:LABX)
RETURN r`. This would take a little time to set up (and perhaps tear down afterwards), and would use more storage, but it is one solution. Another solution is to use [apoc.cypher.run](https://neo4j.com/docs/apoc/current/overview/apoc.cypher/apoc.cypher.run/) with a generated Cypher query where the labels come from the same string.