# Match all relationships between all nodes of a given set of labels

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph with lots of distinct labels. I now want to select all nodes of a given subset of labels and all relationships between them.

I was able to get the expected result with the solution from [How to get all relationships between a set of nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75476285/how-to-get-all-relationships-between-a-set-of-nodes):

```
MATCH (m:A|B|C)-[r]->(n:A|B|C)
RETURN m, r, n
```

but this feels too repetitive. How can I avoid specifying the set of labels, i.e. `A|B|C`, twice?

I tried the following, but it doesn't return all relationships, but only those between a node and itself:

```
MATCH (n:A|B|C)-[r]->(n)
RETURN r, n
```

I'm looking for something like `$labels = :A|B|C MATCH (m:$labels)-[r]->(n:$labels)`

---

Sample data:

```
CREATE (a:A)-[:R]->(b:B)<-[:R]-(c:C)<-[:R]-(c)<-[:R]-(a)-[:R]->(d:D)
```

I want the query to return:

- (a)->(b)
- (c)->(b)
- (c)->(c)
- (a)->(c)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatley, dynamic labels are not a thing in Cypher, yet.

The following query is a lot more verbose but it does not have the repetition. So, depending on your label expression, that may pay off:

```
MATCH (x:A|B|C)
WITH collect(x) as nodes
UNWIND nodes as m
UNWIND nodes as n
MATCH (m)-[r]->(n)
RETURN m, r, n;
```

Comment: Oh, I found `UNWIND` but wasn't able to make it work. It wasn't clear to me that you could unwind the same thing twice. How does this solution compare performance-wise to specifying the labels twice?

Comment: Now `UNWIND nodes as XXX` is duplicated :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more efficient query than the one provided by Arne and also more efficient than providing the labels twice, somehow weird but the query profiles show so.

```
MATCH (n:Person|Movie)
WITH collect(n) AS nodes
MATCH (n)-[r]->(o)
WHERE n IN nodes AND o IN nodes
RETURN n, r, o
```

Comment: This seems to scan a lot more records than the `UNWIND` approach (1800 vs 100). Maybe it depends on the actual number of nodes, labels, and relationships?

Comment: Now `XXX IN nodes` is duplicated :D

Answer (score 0):

Since your query only repeats the list of labels **once**, I wouldn't say its "very" repetitive :-).

1. But if you wanted to, you could just give all the nodes with the desired labels an additional label, say `X` (as in: `MATCH (m:A|B|C) SET m:X`), and then just do:

   ```
   MATCH (m:X)-[r]->(n:X)
   RETURN m, r, n
   ```

   This would take a little time to set up (and perhaps tear down afterwards), would create more overhead during creation of those nodes, and would use more storage, but it is a solution if this issue is important enough to you.
2. Another solution is to use [apoc.cypher.run](https://neo4j.com/docs/apoc/current/overview/apoc.cypher/apoc.cypher.run/) with a generated Cypher query where the labels come from the same string:

   ```
   WITH ":A|B|C" AS labs
   CALL apoc.cypher.run("MATCH (m" + labs +")-[r]->(n" + labs + ") RETURN m, r, n", {}) YIELD value
   RETURN value.m AS m, value.r AS r, value.n AS n
   ```